# Duplicate class after adding dependency in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, leveldb

I added the Java Bayes Classifier by namsor.
Now I get conflicting classes in the library of my project.
Can and how do I remove one of them?

Error:
class org.iq80.leveldb.CompressionType found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.DB found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.DBComparator found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.DBException found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.DBFactory found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.DBIterator found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.Logger found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.Options found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.Range found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.ReadOptions found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.Snapshot found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.WriteBatch found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)
Duplicate class org.iq80.leveldb.WriteOptions found in modules jetified-leveldb-api-0.12 (org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:0.12) and jetified-leveldbjni-all-1.8 (org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.8)

First time user here so thanks

[Error and Project Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H3x5.png)

Comment: If it helps, I downloaded that repository and removed its dependencies of leveldbjni. But cannot get Android Studio to import that dependency locally.

Comment: Please show the code that causes this error.